# sorted function takes 4 arguments?

Tags: python

I've got some code which works. The problem is, the output numbers aren't in order. I looked at the sorted() function and believe that's what I need to use, but when I use it, it says that sorted can only take 4 arguments, I have 6-7.

```
print "Random numbers are: "
for _ in xrange(10):
   print rn(),rn(), rn(), rn(), rn(), rn(), rn() 


with open('Output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("Random numbers are: \n")
    for _ in xrange(500):
        f.write("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" % (rn(), rn(), rn(), rn(), rn(), rn()))
```

How can I sort the output whilst keeping the same format as this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from random import randint

def rn():
    return randint(1,49)

with open('Output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("Random numbers are: \n")
    for _ in xrange(10):
        s = sorted(rn() for _ in xrange(6))
        f.write("{},{},{},{},{},{}\n".format(*s))
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the numbers in a sequence, which is what `sorted()` works with:

```
s = sorted([rn(), rn(), rn(), rn(), rn(), rn()])
```

then pick values from `s` when writing:

```
f.write("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n" % tuple(s))
```

Note that since `s` holds numbers, the format should probably be `%d` as shown, not `%s` which is for strings.

Putting it together, your program should be something like:

```
with open('Output.txt', 'w') as f:
f.write("Random numbers are: \n")
for _ in xrange(500):
    s = sorted([rn(), rn(), rn(), rn(), rn(), rn()])
    f.write("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n" % tuple(s))
```

Assuming the `rn()` function returns a random number, this should give you 500 lines of 6 "fresh" random numbers, sorted on each line.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I added the sorted() function but the problem is, every line of numbers is the same.

Comment: @BubbleMonster Add it inside the for-loop.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - I did, my code looks like this:

print "Random numbers are: "
for _ in xrange(10):
 s = sorted([rn(), rn(), rn(), rn(), rn(), rn()])
    
    
with open('Output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("Random numbers are: \n")
    for _ in xrange(10):
     f.write("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n" % tuple(s))

Comment: @TimPietzcker - def rn():
 return randint(1,49);
 randint.sort()

Comment: You're overwriting the result nine times, and then printing the same line 10 times. Both the function calls and `write`s need to be in the *same* loop.

Comment: Also, you can be glad that `randint.sort()` is never executed because it would trigger an `AttributeError`...

Answer (score 0):

I would use a list for sorting.

Create a list, sort it, format it.

```
import random

def get_numbers():
    return sorted([random.randint(1, 49) for _ in xrange(6)])

with open('Output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("Random numbers are: \n")
    for _ in xrange(10):
        f.write(','.join(map(str, get_numbers())) + '\n')
```

Now you could add some more logic to `get_numbers` like removing duplicate values.

Comment: Sorry didn't see this until now. This does everything perfectly. You're right, I just need to add a get_numbers function now. Thanks